# Codewars Next bigger number with the same digits (Python) на сайте вылетает с ошибкой Execution Timed Out (12000 ms). В чем ошибка?

Tags: python

> Задача звучит: Create a function that takes a positive integer and
> returns the next bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its
> digits. For example:
>
> 12 ==> 21  513 ==> 531 2017 ==> 2071 If the digits can't be
> rearranged to form a bigger number, return -1 (or nil in Swift, None
> in Rust):
>
> 9 ==> -1 111 ==> -1 531 ==> -1

```
def next_bigger(n):
    import itertools
    a=0
    b=0
    spisok_1=list(map(int, str(n)))
    spisok_2=list(itertools.permutations(spisok_1, len(spisok_1)))
    spisok=[]
    for el in spisok_2:
        string = ''
        for i in range(len(el)):
            string+=str(el[i])
            i+=1
        spisok.append(int(string))
    spisok = list(dict.fromkeys(spisok))
    spisok.sort()
    a = spisok.index(n)
    if int(n) == int(spisok[-1]):
        b = -1
    else:
        b = spisok[a + 1]
    return int(b)
    pass
print(next_bigger(531))
```

> Ошибка: Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)
> Как можно оптимизировать код?

Comment: Ну там наверняка какое-то очень-очень большое число на тест подаётся. Странно ещё, что при этом `list(itertools.permutations(...))` всю память не съедает.

Comment: По сути, перебирать **все** варианты - явно контрпродуктивно. Я бы попробовал идти от конца к началу в поисках цифры, меньшей, чем последняя. Как только такая найдена - меняем их местами и готово. Если не найдена, то идём от предпоследней так же. Ну и т.д. Оптимизация - пропускаем одинаковые цифры для последующего поиска. И в целом цифр всего 10, оптимизированный вариант должен работать за O(n), думаю. Там ещё словарь наверняка можно припахать для одинаковых цифр и смещений. Но нужно будет подумать.

Comment: @CrazyElf O_O Зачем такие сложности? надо ж просто найти две самые первые разные цифры с конца и поменять местами.

Comment: @Глеб 2071 -> 2017? Это не будет решением. Или вот такой вариант: 999988887777666665555544443333222211100000, или вот такой: 3333444422222. Всё не так просто, без оптимизаций придётся много раз ходить по числу.

Comment: @CrazyElf, действительно...

Comment: @TimurKarpov, дайте ссылку на задачу, я ее на кодварсе найти не могу.

Comment: Вот ссылка https://www.codewars.com/kata/55983863da40caa2c900004e/train/python

Answer (score 2):

Ну, за разумное время задача решается так:

```
def next_bigger(num):
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
    ind = len(digits) - 1
    while ind >= 1 and digits[ind - 1] >= digits[ind]:
        ind -= 1
    if not ind:
        return -1
    pivot = digits[ind - 1]
    swap_ind = len(digits) - 1
    while pivot >= digits[swap_ind]:
        swap_ind -= 1
    digits[swap_ind], digits[ind - 1] = digits[ind - 1], digits[swap_ind]
    digits[ind:] = digits[:ind - 1:-1]
    return int(''.join(str(x) for x in digits))
```

Вывод:

```
1234567989
531
2071
-1
-1
-1
```

В решении используется *Next lexicographical permutation algorithm*.

Немного более красивый (но не такой быстрый) алгоритм:

```
def next_bigger(n):
    s = list(str(n))
    for i in range(len(s) - 2, -1, -1):
        if s[i] < s[i+1]:
            t = s[i:]
            m = min(filter(lambda x: x > t[0], t))
            t.remove(m)
            t.sort()
            s[i:] = [m] + t
            return int("".join(s))
    return -1
```